# Copy columns until last row from one sheet and paste to the next empty row of another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the below VBA code which is copying a range from Sheet1 and paste it in the same sheet. However i need to paste the data in the next available row of sheet2.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5").Copy

Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

Please help me out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is good but one line you need to change it, that is place `Sheets("Sheet2").Activate` line **before** `lastrow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row`

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5").Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

    Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  How to copy on a specifc Sheet2 cell range? e.g.  If I want to copy to Sheet2 D5.

Comment: then add Range("D5").pastespecial instead of cells(lastrow+1... thats all

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

lastrow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set rng1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5")
Set rng2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & lastrow + 1)

rng1.Copy
rng2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: You may have to qualify Rows.count as well. `...Cells(sheets(Sheet2").Rows.Count, "A").`

Answer (score 0):

First activate the sheet2 and then find last row

```
lastrow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
```